# C - free() error

Tags: c

This is my function where I am debugging:

```
boolean
adin_memory(char* buffer, int size_chunck, int end_flag){
    global_buffer = mymalloc(size_chunck*sizeof(char)); //3
    global_buffer = buffer;

    real_data= (SP16 *)mymalloc(size_chunck*sizeof(SP16));  //3
    memcpy(real_data,global_buffer,size_chunck);

    free(global_buffer); //ERROR

    pos_escrita += size_chunck;

    global_size = size_chunck;
    global_end_flag = end_flag;
    return TRUE;
}
```

And this is `mymalloc` function:

```
void *
mymalloc(size_t size)
{
  void *p;
  if ( (p = malloc(size)) == NULL) {
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN32__)
    jlog("Error: mymalloc: failed to allocate %Iu bytes\n", size);
#else
    jlog("Error: mymalloc: failed to allocate %zu bytes\n", size);
#endif
    *((char*)0) = 0 ; //###ARL provoca um exception
    exit(1);
  }
  return p;
}
```

I am getting this error when `free()` functions is called. Why?
[image]

Comment: @user3121023 this should be an answer (and btw, `global_buffer` being defined nowhere in this code seems to be indeed a global variable ... very strange)

Comment: suggest to call an `malloc()`-wrapper checking for OOM `xmalloc()` as per widely used convention.

Comment: further suggest not to cast pointers returned from `malloc()` (or, more general, `void *` pointers)

Comment: And one more problem-unrelated suggestion: As `sizeof(char)` equals `1` *per definition*, just leave that factor out, it doesn't serve a purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems that I see:

```
global_buffer = mymalloc(size_chunck*sizeof(char)); //3
global_buffer = buffer;
```

That results in a memory leak. The value returned by `mymalloc` is now lost.

```
real_data= (SP16 *)mymalloc(size_chunck*sizeof(SP16));  //3
memcpy(real_data,global_buffer,size_chunck);

free(global_buffer); //ERROR
```

That will be a problem depending on how `buffer` was defined. The above statement is equivalent to:

```
free(buffer);
```

It's hard to say why that is an error without seeing how the function was called. It's hard to suggest what should be changed without understanding the bigger picture. To be more specific, it is not clear why you needed to use:

```
global_buffer = buffer;
```

Comment: You say everything. Thanks

Comment: @jdscardoso, you are welcome. I am glad i was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning global_buffer to 'buffer' which is an address unknown to the heap.  That's why you are getting an error.  Don't do the second assignment to global_buffer.

Also, you should check for an earlier error so you don't accidentally try to free the null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

from first sight:

```
//you allocate memory and store it in global_buffer
global_buffer = mymalloc(size_chunck*sizeof(char)); //3

// you overwrite global_buffer by a new value of buffer
global_buffer = buffer;

// global_buffer no more hold the address of memory allocated
// but you still want to free it
...
free(global_buffer);
```